# Installing new versions of Python on Cygwin does not install Pip?

Tags: python, cygwin, pip

While I am aware of the option of [installing Pip from source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html), I'm trying to avoid going down that path so that updates to Pip will be managed by Cygwin's package management.

I've [recently learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/2489598) that the latest versions of Python include Pip.  However, even though I have recently installed the latest versions of Python from the Cygwin repos, Bash doesn't recognize a valid Pip install on the system.

```
896/4086 MB RAM 0.00 0.00 0.00 1/12 Tue, Jun 16, 2015 ( 3:53:22am CDT) [0 jobs]
[ethan@firetail: +2] ~ $ python -V
Python 2.7.10
892/4086 MB RAM 0.00 0.00 0.00 1/12 Tue, Jun 16, 2015 ( 3:53:27am CDT) [0 jobs]
[ethan@firetail: +2] ~ $ python3 -V
Python 3.4.3
883/4086 MB RAM 0.00 0.00 0.00 1/12 Tue, Jun 16, 2015 ( 3:53:34am CDT) [0 jobs]
[ethan@firetail: +2] ~ $ pip
bash: pip: command not found
878/4086 MB RAM 0.00 0.00 0.00 1/12 Tue, Jun 16, 2015 ( 3:53:41am CDT) [0 jobs]
[ethan@firetail: +2] ~ $ pip2
bash: pip2: command not found
876/4086 MB RAM 0.00 0.00 0.00 1/12 Tue, Jun 16, 2015 ( 3:53:42am CDT) [0 jobs]
[ethan@firetail: +2] ~ $ pip3
bash: pip3: command not found
```

Note that the installed Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.4.3 are both recent enough that they should include Pip.

Is there something that I might have overlooked?  Could there be a new install of Pip that isn't in the standard binary directories referenced in the $PATH?  If the Cygwin packages of Python do in fact lack an inclusion of Pip, is that something that's notable enough to warrant a bug report to the Cygwin project?

Comment: Interesting shell prompt.

Comment: You can try `python -m pip` to see if pip is actually installed in your interpreter. In the latest versions `python -m ensurepip` should bootstrap pip, if it's not already present. On pip's website you can also find `get-pip.py` to bootstrap pip.

Comment: @rr- I'm a customization junkie.  My prompt's a modification of one that I found online.  I can't easily find the original source, but [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) is an example of the basics.  I use both $PROMPT_COMMAND and $PS1; on a non-Cygwin system, it would make sense to implement the first line as $PROMPT_COMMAND and the second as $PS1 (so that pressing enter on a blank line looks right), but on Cygwin, I put some of the first line in $PS1 to reduce forks for performance reasons.

Comment: @cel `python -m pip` produced `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`, but running `python -m ensurepip` seems to have installed pip, as verified by running `pip` in bash.  Having said that, I don't know whether future updates to Python through Cygwin will also update Pip; that was my original goal in posting this question.

Answer (score 105):

[cel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272172/cel) self-answered this question in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863501/installing-new-versions-of-python-on-cygwin-does-not-install-pip/31958249#comment49786910_30863501). For posterity, let's convert this helpfully working solution into a genuine answer.

Unfortunately, Cygwin currently fails to:

- Provide `pip`, `pip2`, or `pip3` packages.
- Install the `pip` and `pip2` commands when the `python` package is installed.
- Install the `pip3` command when the `python3` package is installed.

It's time to roll up our grubby command-line sleeves and get it done ourselves.

### What's the Catch?

Since *no* `pip` packages are currently available, the answer to the specific question of "Is `pip` installable as a Cygwin package?" is technically "Sorry, son."

That said, `pip` *is* trivially installable via a one-liner. This requires manually re-running said one-liner to update `pip` but has the distinct advantage of actually working. (Which is more than we usually get in Cygwin Land.)

### `pip3` Installation, Please

**To install `pip3`,** the Python 3-specific version of `pip`, under Cygwin:

```
$ python3 -m ensurepip
```

This assumes the `python3` Cygwin package to have been installed, of course.

### `pip2` Installation, Please

**To install both `pip` and `pip2`,** the Python 2-specific versions of `pip`, under Cygwin:

```
$ python -m ensurepip
```

This assumes the `python` Cygwin package to have been installed, of course.

Comment: @cel is actually the one to credit as the source for the answer; he was the first to propose that solution.

Comment: Oh! Quite right. You're awesome too, of course. (_This has been fixed._)

Comment: After installing, to upgrade `pip` to the latest version, run `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: upgrading pip2  causes pip3 to vanish. and `python3 -m ensurepip` does not work again.

Comment: I got back access to my `pip3` by `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: The steps first would be even better. If I have to read through all the explanations, chances are high I boil out. Simple solution steps first and then the explanation would be better (also for your points ;-)

Comment: I deleted the `python` and `pip` file link associations in `\usr\bin` so that I now have to explicitly request a python/pip version (thus avoiding the "which python is this" conundrum).

Comment: Added a supporting video here in actual action in my cygwin: https://asciinema.org/a/hSu4kmJ6wb7b2UiuvxiXqtgGK

Answer (score 8):

1. Download a helper package:

   - For Python 2.x install the [`python-setuptools`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=/python-setuptools) package.
   - For Python 3.x install the [`python3-setuptools`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=/python3-setuptools) package.
2. Run the script:

   - For Python 2.7 run: `easy_install-2.7 pip`
   - For Python 3.4 run: `easy_install-3.4 pip`

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow Cygwin's package manager to keep Pip updated (which was my initial goal).  It's also more complicated than cel's comment (which was codified into an answer by Cecil) due to requiring another package and specifying an exact version number.  It may be useful to legacy Python users, though.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason my install of pip was broken, and `python -m ensurepip` wasn't able to resurrect. But `easy_install-2.7 --upgrade pip` worked like a charm.